# PHP MYSQL need to group rows that have same value in certain column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a table named 'entries' with the columns: originator, collaborator, engagement_partner, niche, and fee_potential. Some of the rows in the table have the same originator. I have a form that someone fills out, submits it to the database. I have tried using GROUP BY, but need some assistance on this.

My WordPress SQL statement: This will be used in the WordPress function file.

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM entries group by originator");
```

I need to display the data in a table format below. Basically, I need to group each entry based on Originator that are the same.

```html
<table class="table">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Originator</th>
     <th>Collaborator</th>
     <th>engagement_partner</th>
     <th>Niche</th>
     <th>Fee Potential</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td><b>First Originator</b></td>
         <td>Company Name</td>
         <td>Engagement Partner</td>
         <td>Web</td>
         <td>$40000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><b>First Originator</b></td>
         <td>Company Name</td>
         <td>Engagement Partner</td>
         <td>Web</td>
         <td>$40000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><b>First Originator</b></td>
         <td>Company Name</td>
         <td>Engagement Partner</td>
         <td>Web</td>
         <td>$40000</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<br>

<table class="table">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Originator</th>
     <th>Collaborator</th>
     <th>engagement_partner</th>
     <th>Niche</th>
     <th>Fee Potential</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td><b>Second Originator</b></td>
         <td>Company Name</td>
         <td>Engagement Partner</td>
         <td>Web</td>
         <td>$40000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><b>Second Originator</b></td>
         <td>Company Name</td>
         <td>Engagement Partner</td>
         <td>Web</td>
         <td>$40000</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use php to generate the formatting. `GROUP BY` doesn't seem to map to what you need. It means to aggregate a results (like SUM per Niche), not to list them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you fetch all the entries and group them with php like so;

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM entries");
$originators = [];
foreach($rows as $row)
{ 
    $originators[$row->originator][] = $row;
}
```

then loop through the originators to fill the table, something like this:

```
<?php
foreach($originators as $originator => $entries){
?>

   <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Originator</th>
        <th>Collaborator</th>
        <th>engagement_partner</th>
        <th>Niche</th>
        <th>Fee Potential</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($entries as $entry){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><b> <?php echo $entry->originator; ?></b></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->collaborator; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->engagement_partner; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->niche; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->fee_potential;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php}?>
```

Comment: Is this correct `$originators[$row['originator']][] = $row;` it seems to fail on that.

Comment: Can you try this $originators[$row->originator][] = $row;

Comment: It shows the column names and first originator name, but no more rows or even data for other columns for the first originator.

Comment: Yes. That’s where it at least showed the columns names and one originator but the rest of the row doesn’t have the data and loops to next originator isn’t showing.

Comment: can you try `<?php foreach($entries as $entry){ print_r('TYPE: '. gettype($entry));?>` so i know the type of the variable

Comment: I think it failing before that, cause that didn't do anything different. Here is dropbox link for the screenshot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/902d5o4mrrorhbm/Screen%20Shot%202019-02-20%20at%207.34.46%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi @Anthony `<?php var_dump($entries); die('End Here'); foreach($entries as $entry){ ?>` try this and take a screenshot of the response.

Comment: Here is screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/80bkiehwezr3evf/Screen%20Shot%202019-02-20%20at%208.08.10%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: here is a screenshot of all the code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vppum6g6tppv1mp/Screen%20Shot%202019-02-20%20at%208.09.05%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Check this part `<?php foreach($entries as $entry){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><b> <?php echo $entry->originator; ?></b></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->collaborator; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->engagement_partner; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->niche; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->fee_potential;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>`
you didn't take the editted version

Comment: Yes @Anthony, we can

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't looks like a GROUP BY statement is what you are looking for.

Seeing your example HTML structure, the thing you are looking for is an ordered list of rows. You can then use php to sort the results and then use them

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `entries`");
$sortedRows = [];

foreach($rows as $row) {
    if (!isset($sortedRows[$row->originator])) {
        $sortedRows[$row->originator] = [];
    }
    $sortedRows[$row->originator][] = $row;
}
```

a different approach is using ORDER BY in the query, which i won't fully work out since i dont know what your approach is on creating the HTML structure:

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `entries` ORDER BY `originator` ASC");
$currentOriginator = NULL;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   if ($row->originator !== $currentOriginator) {
       //create table
       $currentOriginator = $row->originator;
   }
   //add the row to the table
}
```